# React test function inside onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following stateless component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = ({ name, onChange, type }) => (
  <input 
    name={name}
    onChange={onChange}
    type={type} />
);

export default Input
```

a util function like so:

```
export const getValue = e => ({ 
    name: e.target.getAttribute('name'),
    value: e.target.value
})
```

and my test like so:

```
it('should call the onChange for the input element', () => {
  const event = {target: {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}};
  const input = shallow(<Input onChange={getValue} />)
  input.simulate('change', event)
})
```

the error I get from the test is:

```
TypeError: e.target.getAttribute is not a function
```

I was not expecting to get this error by passing the mocked event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

event object that you passed to the `simulate` function does not have `target.getAttribute` function. You can simply add it there:

```
const attrs = {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}
const event = {target: { getAttribute: name => attrs[name], ...attrs }};
```